# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated [BYAPR21CA0017.namprd21.prod.outlook.com]

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office365, smtpclient

I am getting this error message when I try to send mail.

**The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [BYAPR21CA0017.namprd21.prod.outlook.com]**

Following is my code:

```
public static string SendMail(string ToEmail, string Subj, string Message, string mailHostAdd, string mailSenderId, string mailPassword)
    {
      try
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            //string HostAdd = mailHostAdd.ToString();
            string HostAdd = "smtp.office365.com";
           
            string FromEmailid = mailSenderId.ToString();
            string Pwd = mailPassword.ToString();

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(FromEmailid.ToString(), ToEmail.ToString(), Subj.ToString(), Message.ToString());
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient mailclient = new SmtpClient();
            NetworkCredential smtpuser = new NetworkCredential(FromEmailid, Pwd);

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = smtpuser;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Host = HostAdd;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;

            smtp.Send(message);
            return "Mail sent successfully!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
```

Please help.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the relevant parts of the error. **The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.** and **Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail** are the meaningful portions.

Comment: @KenWhite can you please help me to sort out this error?